# Confirmar exclusão com sweet alert2 e laravel 7?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade, sweetalert2

Tenho um botão:

```html
<button class="btn-floating red btn-small" data-id="{{ $tag->id }}" data-action="{{url("/admin/tags/{$tag->id}") }}" onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$tag->id}})">
   <i class="material-icons red">delete</i>
</button>
```

Que manda para uma função em Javascript, que está assim:

```js
function deleteConfirmation(id) {

  swal.fire({
    title: "Excluir?",
    text: "Isso não poderá ser desfeito!",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: !0,
    confirmButtonText: "Sim, excluir!",
    cancelButtonText: "Não, cancelar!",
    reverseButtons: !0
  }).then(function (e) {
    if (e.value === true) {
      var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      console.log(CSRF_TOKEN)

      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: "/admin/tags/"+id,
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (results) {

          if (results.success === true) {
            swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
          } else {
            swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
          }
        }
      });

    } else {
      e.dismiss;
    }

  }, function (dismiss) {
    return false;
  })
}
```

Mas quando envio está dando metodo não permitido. Acredito que não seja questão de rotas. Mas por garantia as rotas aqui:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
    Route::put('/posts/{post}/publish', 'PostController@publish')->middleware('admin');
    Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoryController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('/tags', 'TagController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('/comments', 'CommentController', ['only' => ['index', 'destroy']]);
    Route::resource('/users', 'UserController', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'only' => ['index', 'destroy']]);
});
```

Quando mudo meu método para POST ele da o mesmo erro de método não permitido mas no allowed methods ele da que delete é um deles. Já dei print no token também e ele puxa normalmente.

Notei que quando eu clico em confirmar ele vem primeiro um Found:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que vem o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo seria criar algo que solicitasse confirmação antes de excluir. Tentei criar algo pelo controller mas tive problemas na parte do `.then` em diante então resolvi seguir no ajax e javascript que foi o que chegou mais perto de funcionar.

O problema aqui é que além de não estar funcionando eu vou ter que criar uma classe dessa para cada url diferente que for requisitar, ou tem um jeito mais fácil?

Comment: Quando você utiliza Route::resource, o Laravel monta a rota `DELETE` com um parâmetro `{id}`. Por algum motivo, a chamada do seu `DELETE` tá sem o `id` no final.

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo! Antes de deixar como coloquei aqui eu tinha feito dessa forma aqui:

```url: "{{url('/admin/tags')}}/" + id,``` mas mesmo assim sem sucesso

Comment: Porque não usa o `data` ao invés do `id`? Não vi o que tem antes, mas chuto que corre o risco de estar sendo sobrescrito. Tente `url: $(this).data('url')` e remova o `onclick`, adicionando o `$('.btn-deletar').on('click', deleteConfirmation)`....